# Is the Infiniti-Lift in Tiny Death Star worth the bux?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have 60 floors in TDS and bought the Ultra-Lift (tips x4) many moons ago. However, I'm now unsure whether saving 499 bux for the Infini-Lift (tips x5) is worth it. Has anyone bought it already? Does it really make much of a difference or is using the bux to make more credits a better use of them?

Answer (score 2):

Buy it. I have it and with near 100 levels, I'd be going insane without it.
Also, if you are going to use your bux for credits,  it's a bit of a waste.  Get the best elevator you can and you'll make more credits without having to waste bux

Comment: Just be aware that it can make delivery to specific levels difficult.  Especially for the purposes of cut scenes. My advice would be to put any levels with locked cut scenes at the very top and very bottom of your tower,  so that you don't drive by them.

Comment: Also, a x5 tip turns into a x10 tip with "?" Bitizens. As opposed to x4/x8.

Comment: Thanks - I guess I'll be patient and wait for it. Out of interest, what do you do with your bux now you have all the lifts? The most efficient use for them I've come up with so far is buying triple coin stock.

Comment: I would use the bux to upgrade the levels, so that you don't have to refill them so often.

Comment: I save mine for any events. I've got so much credits I don't need to buy any more.  I find them very useful getting the limited edition characters and levels.

Comment: Credits will come, don't really see the point in exchanging bux for them.

Comment: Oh, I have also used bux to buy key bitizens in order to unlock scenes. That pesky mon calamari just wouldn't show up so I caved and bought one to unlock the scene.